# How to find the highest and minimum value of count in sql

Tags: sql

This was my question "Write the SQL command to find the film(s) with the largest cast. Find the film(s) with the smallest cast. In both cases, also return the size of the cast."

---

My code is:

```
Select max(count), min(count)
From (Select mov_title, count(act_id) as count
From movie natural join movie_cast
Group by mov_title
Order by count desc) as t;
```

but by using this, I am getting the max and min count of the same movie although I want the movie which has the most cast and the movie with the least cast.

This is the structure of tables:

- actor(act_id, act_name)
- movie_cast(act_id, mov_id)
- movie(mov_id,  mov_title)

Comment: Don't use the so-called "natural join".

Answer (score 0):

If your version of SQL support analytic functions, then `RANK` is one straightforward way to handle this requirement:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT mov_title, COUNT(act_id) AS count,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(act_id)) rnk_lowest,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(act_id) DESC) rnk_highest
    FROM movie
    NATURAL JOIN movie_cast
    GROUP BY mov_title
)

SELECT mov_title, count,
       CASE WHEN rnk_lowest = 1 THEN 'lowest' ELSE 'highest' END AS label
FROM cte
WHERE rnk_lowest = 1 OR rnk_highest = 1
ORDER BY count;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use sqlserver:

```
Select top 1 mov_title, count(act_id) as count
From movie natural join movie_cast
Group by mov_title
order by count
union 
Select top 1 mov_title, count(act_id) as count
From movie natural join movie_cast
Group by mov_title
order by count desc
```

inMySql:

```
Select mov_title, count(act_id) as count
From movie natural join movie_cast
Group by mov_title
order by count
LIMIT 1
union 
Select mov_title, count(act_id) as count
From movie natural join movie_cast
Group by mov_title
order by count desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi Somaye, actually I'm using MySQL and it does not support "top". It shows an error because even I tried the same thing, but I really appreciate the idea of Union. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi.I did edit and add script for MySql.I hope it works.